# Rails render partial with :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is so simple it shouldnt be an issue but I dont understand whats going on here.

I have the following code

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    def bookings
      @bookings = Booking.all
    end
end
```

/views/dashboard/bookings.html.erb

```
<%= render 'booking', :collection => @bookings %>
```

/views/dashboard/_booking.html.erb

```
<%= booking.booking_time %>
```

I get the following error

```
undefined method `booking_time' for nil:NilClass
```

However if I do this in /views/dashboard/_bookings.html.erb

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
   <%= render 'booking', :booking => booking %>
<% end %>
```

I get (correct)

```
2012-12-19 09:00:00 UTC 
2012-12-28 03:00:00 UTC
```

Whats going on here? I really want to use :collection as defined here 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an old question but just case others are struggling with it

> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the
>   individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the
>   collection being rendered **via a variable named after the partial**.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

In the example above from the OP, because the partial was called `booking` instead of `bookings`, Rails was failing to infer the member name to be used in the partial, hence the need to pass it explicitly as `as: :booking`

Answer (score 4):

Your call to render is different than what is shown in the guide.  Have you tried `render :partial => 'booking', :collection => @bookings`?

I believe you should also be able to use the shorter alternative assuming you are in Rails 3 or later: `render @bookings`.

Comment: Thanks. yea I've tried render :partial => 'booking', :collection => @bookings - but its the same

Comment: Odd, does adding :as => :booking to the render call change anything?

Comment: `:as => :booking` fixed this for me, I guess it doesn't do any rails magic to infer the singular name from the collection.