# Organizing shared partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, partials

We keep our shared partials in the `app/views/shared` lib.

So for example if I want to display the comments for a specific post I could do the following:

`app/views/shared/_comment.html.erb`:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= comment.body %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

`app/views/posts/show.html.erb`:

```
.
.
.
  <%= link_to 'Show Comments', '#', id: 'show-comments-link' %>
  <section id="comments-section">
  
    <table id="comments-table">
      <tbody>
        <%= render partial: 'shared/comment', collection: @comments %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </section>
  
</section>
```

See how I'm able to render the partial by referencing it's *location* in the `app/views/shared` lib and *name* as the same as it's filename but without the preceding `_` or ending `.html.erb`?

It's this line right here:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/comment', collection: @comments %>
```

Working with partials is a great example of where Rails chooses [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). There are many conventions here.

Focusing on the filenames, locations, and code organization (and skipping over [rendering collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350280/2909897)). I think this quote from [Agile Web Development with Rails 5](https://pragprog.com/book/rails5/agile-web-development-with-rails-5) is very helpful:

> If the first option or `:partial` parameter to a `render` call is a simple name, Rails assumes that the target template is in the current controller’s `view` directory. However, if the name contains one or more `/` characters, Rails assumes that the part up to the last slash is a directory name and the rest is the template name. The directory is assumed to be under `app/views`. This makes it easy to share partials and subtemplates across controllers.
>
> The convention among Rails applications is to store these shared partials in a subdirectory of `app/views` called `shared`.

Now I'm curious about how I should add a form to create a new comment to be placed at the end of the `comments-section`.

- Should I also put it in the `app/views/shared` dir, name it `_comment_form.html.erb`, and continue to reference it as `'shared/comment_form'`?
- Should I move everything into the `app/views/comments` dir, name it `_form.html.erb`, and reference it as `'comments/form'` (and go against the `shared` dir convention)?
- Also what about the new comment, Should I create a `@new_comment = Comment.new` inside the `Posts#show` action?
- What are some general guidelines you follow to help make decisions about how to organize your shared partials? (maybe it should go in the `shared/comments/_form.html.erb`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no definitive guide to this. It is all based on your file management preference.

However, keeping `'comments/form'` your resource forms (POST/PUT action related items) within the scope of that resources' view namespace makes more sense than dumping it in `views/shared` as it can get very messy when all the partials with similar names from different resources get mixed up. I would recommend namespaced `views/shared/comments` to keep snippets for looping templates like `shared/comments/comments_on_homepage`, `shared/comments/comments_for_admin`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

this might can help you:

= render partial: "shared/comment", collection: @comments, as: :comment